# CakePHP error set data to ModelA from ModelB

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**My load models:**

```
array (size=14)
  0 => string 'AppModel' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Log' (length=3)
  2 => string 'LogAppModel' (length=11)
  3 => string 'User' (length=4)
```

I'm trying pass data from model User to Log using set http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-set-one-two-null

```
$this->Log->set('test','data');
```

But cake give me error

```
Error: Call to a member function set() on null  
File: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Javi/Sites/log/app/Model/User.php 
Line: 198
```

**User Model:**

```
public function afterSave($created, $options = array()){
        //var_dump(App::objects('model'));die();
        $this->Log->set('test','data'); <------ Line 198
        $this->log('log textttttttttt','status');
    }
```

So I need pass an id from afterSave in User model to beforeSave in Log model

**Log model:**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['user_id'] = AuthComponent::user('id');
        $this->data[$this->alias]['project_id'] = //I NEED THIS!!!!!!!!;
        return parent::beforeSave($options);
    }
```

Why I can't pass data from User model to Log model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `set()` is of `controller`'s method.

Comment: damn, isn't possible send from model?

Comment: You can define a custom function in the model and use the class register method to access that function. But I am not sure this will work properly.